# cgroup rt support in Debian Buster (Kernel 4.19.0)

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, cgroup

Is it possible to enable the ***cgroup rt*** support in Debian Buster (kernel 4.19.0) without recompiling the kernel? Perhaps with a grub configuration parameter? Thanks.

Background: Docker logs this warnings:

```
Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period
Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a realtime kernel.

eg.

```
$ sudo apt install linux-image-rt-amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to move away from the 4.19.0 kernel anyway, also because it is buggy in handling >8 network streams in its vxlan codepath.